# Solr query not operator for filtering string array

Tags: solr, solr-query-syntax

I want to return all the documents which doesn't have "hello" string in the "test" key.
So, I created following query which is not filtering the documents containing "hello"
q: -test:("hello")

```
[{
 "test":["hello", "second"],
  id:123
},
{
 "test":["hello1", "second1"],
  id:1234
}
]
```

Expected result:

```
[
 "test":["hello1", "second1"],
  id:1234
}
]
```

Comment: What is the field definition for test?

Comment: Just checked your case over my Solr installation, your query works. Can you provide entire json/xml answer from Solr including query and result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"test" is a string with multivalued=true and indexed=false. Seems like the filtering in solr works only for indexed fields. Once I made the field "test" indexed the filtering is working fine.